# Setting up KLEE for testing a specific Linux kernel function

Tags: c, linux-kernel, klee

I am currently working on a project where I need to test a specific Linux kernel function using KLEE. The function in question is btrfs_map_block located in fs/btrfs/volumes.c, and I am focusing on addressing the vulnerability CVE-2019-19816.

Problem:
I am unsure about the steps to set up this function to be compatible with KLEE for testing purposes. Additionally, I would like to understand how to incorporate the necessary Linux headers for accurate testing.

Question:
What steps should I follow to prepare the btrfs_map_block function for testing with KLEE?
How can I ensure the inclusion of relevant Linux headers for proper functioning of the function during KLEE testing?

Important Note:
Please provide clear and detailed instructions, and if possible, include examples or references to documentation that can aid in this process. Thank you.

I've experimented with copying other dependent functions.
I attempted to directly incorporate the header file into KLEE's setup.
I explored alternative approaches to replicating the function's dependencies.

Comment: "How can I ensure the inclusion of relevant Linux headers for proper functioning of the function during KLEE testing?" - If you bother about specifying proper include directories and macro definitions for standalone compilation of the kernel source file, then you could e.g. generate `compile_commands.json` file, which contains all those options. Please note, that Stack Overflow is not about providing "detailed instructions" for doing something. We answer questions about specific problems.